# linq - dynamic group by different functions of date

Tags: c#, linq

below my simple sql query

```
SELECT source, date ,COUNT (*) 
FROM query 
WHERE source in ('a value')
GROUP BY source, date
```

it took me a while to understand and implement it in linq notation (also thanks to hints from this site) by finally I did it

```
var selekt = dt.AsEnumerable();
var alldata = from ad in selekt
             where ad["source"].ToString().Equals(this.comboBox1.Text)
             group ad by new 
             {
                err = ad["err"], 
                date = ad["date"] 
             }into g
             orderby g.Key.err ascending, g.Key.channel descending
             select new 
             { 
                Name = g.Key.err, 
                Date = g.Key.date, 
                C = g.Count()
             };
```

It is more or less what I need, it also contains "dynamic" element in where clause.
The last point I can't get it is dynamic group clause. 
Depends on values on the form I want to group this query by one of three functions of date:  day/week/month. I suppose the most difficult part could be group by week. 
Anyway, every hint regarding this topis are welcome

Comment: can you provide sample of three functions for group?

Comment: day and month is easy:
dataD = Convert.ToDateTime(ad["data"]).ToShortDateString()

dataM = Convert.ToDateTime(ad["data"]).Month()

I am thinking right now about additional column in my datatable with number of week

Comment: how you want detect what method should be used?

Comment: there is a group of checkboxes in my winform: day/week/month. 
To make it easier I added to my datatable column week. So now I can use one of group method:
dataD = Convert.ToDateTime(ad["data"]).ToShortDateString() 
dataW = ad["week"]
dataM = Convert.ToDateTime(ad["data"]).Month()

Right now the point is how to choose correct one?

Comment: is it possible to concat parts of linq query ?   Something like select part + where part + grouppart

Comment: it is  possible. you can use function that return value what you need

Comment: I would just make overloads for every combination